# jQuery remove closest on multiple DOM elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following loop:

```
<% @team.authority_emails.collect.each_with_index do |a_e, index| %>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="large-11 columns">
      <input type="text" value="<%= a_e %>">
   </div>
   <div class="large-1 columns">
    <a href="#" id="aERemove"><%= icon('fa fa-remove') %></a>
   </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Which returns:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-11 columns">
     <input type="text" value="new@email.com">
   </div>
   <div class="large-1 columns">
     <a href="#" id="aERemove"><i class="fa fa-fa fa-remove"></i></a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="large-11 columns">
     <input type="text" value="nup@asdf.com">
   </div>
   <div class="large-1 columns">
     <a href="#" id="aERemove"><i class="fa fa-fa fa-remove"></i></a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('#aERemove').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  return false;
});
```

Each `input` that is created by my loop needs to be deletable `<a href="#" id="aERemove"><%= icon('fa fa-remove') %></a>`. My current jQuery only works on the first `#aERemove` id and none of the proceeding id's. How do make remove work on every input that is created within my loop?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: As j0 said, if you use  `class="aERemove"` and in jQuery: `$(".aERemove")` it should work.

Comment: Ahhhhhh I see. whoops.

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of ID as ID **must** be unique.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-11 columns">
     <input type="text" value="new@email.com">
   </div>
   <div class="large-1 columns">
     <a href="#" class="aERemove"><i class="fa fa-fa fa-remove"></i></a>
   </div>
 </div>

$('.aERemove').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  return false;
});
```